# Intersect comma separated lists in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have to compare two comma separated lists in one sql statement.

Basically it is for querying a target table which has in one column a comma separated list of ids and the search's target table return again a list of ids.

I tried this

```
SELECT * FROM target_table 
 WHERE commaSeparatedListInOneColumn IN (
 SELECT id FROM searchTable WHERE name LIKE '%searchString%')
```

But i am not getting the data. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: and the problem is?

Comment: And now you understand why storing data in a comma separated list in a single column **is a terrible idea**. Refactor your database design

Comment: So this is de Design of the Framework I am using. The condition is queried on the object struckture. So it is not an option to change the db structure.

Comment: Please do tell, which Framework are you using

Comment: please send you data formats and DB data sample on your question

Comment: Its Pimcore, the MultiHref relation is stored as comma separated list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write query like this

```
 SELECT * FROM target_table 
      WHERE commaSeparatedListInOneColumn REGEXP (
      SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR '|') FROM searchTable WHERE name LIKE '%searchString%' group by name 
      )
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If `commaSeparatedListInOneColumn` contain value like `1,2,3,45`
 and you have string like `12,2,4,5` and if you want to check that any of  `12,2,4,5` ids is present in `commaSeparatedListInOneColumn` or not.

Then you can do this with the help of **find_in_set()**.

Just like this

```
$ids='12,2,4,5';
$filterKeys = explode(',',$ids);
$searchQuery='';
foreach ($filterKeys as $word) {
    $word = trim($word);
    if ($word) {
        $searchQuery = $searchQuery . "find_in_set('$word', trim(`commaSeparatedListInOneColumn`)) > 0 or ";
    }
}
$searchQuery = chop($searchQuery, ' or ');
$finalQuery="SELECT * FROM target_table WHERE $searchQuery";
```

Here `$finalQuery` contains the query it look like this

```
SELECT * FROM target_table 
WHERE find_in_set('12', trim(`commaSeparatedListInOneColumn`)) > 0 or 
find_in_set('2', trim(`commaSeparatedListInOneColumn`)) > 0 or
 find_in_set('4', trim(`commaSeparatedListInOneColumn`)) > 0 or 
find_in_set('5', trim(`commaSeparatedListInOneColumn`)) > 0
```

I thing it will help you.